# Firebase - good use case for set() instead of update()

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, crud

I'm building create, update and delete operations in my app that uses Firebase. Regarding [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38924648/4691187) on a question about the difference between `set()` and `update()`, @jmk2142 suggested that creating, updating and deleting an item in firebase could all be done with `update()`.

Apart from semantics / understanding the purpose of the code, is there any good reason NOT to use `update()` for all of these?

Answer (score 8):

If you want to replace the entire value in a location, you'll want to use `set()`.

If you want to update specific properties or paths under a location, use `update()`.