# Writing data to firebase without overwriting it. Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I just got my app working on firebase, I just have the small problem of it overwriting the data.

The action:

```
 @IBAction func Gem(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.ref.child("users").child(Personnr.text!).setValue(["Fornavn": Fornavn.text!])
    self.ref.child("users").child(Personnr.text!).setValue(["Efternavn": Efternavn.text!])
}
```

The problem is that it writes the first command, then erases it and writes the second one.
Im new to programming, so its probably something simply.

I have clarified text fields from which the user will write the data which will then be uploaded to the database.

```
@IBOutlet weak var Fornavn: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var Efternavn: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var Personnr: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var Korekort: UITextField!
```

Any clues on how to avoid the overwrite?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45941497/7715250

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is pretty normal so what you can do is make a dictionary like this

```
let data = ["Fornavn": Fornavn.text!,"Efternavn": Efternavn.text!]
```

And then do

```
self.ref.child("users").child(Personnr.text!).setValue(data)
```

What this does is that it stores both Fornavn and Efternavn data under the Personnr.text Parent node

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a node with name `Personnr.text`.

If you want to add more child nodes or update current data on this node, you can use `updateChildValues` function

Btw, you can optimize your query by:

`self.ref.child("users").child(Personnr.text!)
.updateChildValues(["Fornavn": Fornavn.text!],["Efternavn": Efternavn.text!])`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
let arrVal = [["Fornavn": Fornavn.text!],["Efternavn": Efternavn.text!]]
self.ref.child("users").child(Personnr.text!).updateChildValues(arrVal)
```

Reference:https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write