# Firebase Functions API, .update() overwriting object

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have an API with HTTP endpoint which is on Firebase Functions. It takes care of some processing of received data which is then stored into Firebase Realtime Database, but I'm having a constant problem where a part of object overwrites entire object, making the data invalid and not useful. The problem is that when Google Geocoding completes, the object is already in database and it gets overwritten by `location` object that was created, despite I used the `.update()` and have set full object paths. I have confirmed that the data is already there by adding a few `console.log()` functions and then viewing the Functions logs.

Function that receives the data and process it (some stuff removed like image processing, otherwise the function is too long to be pasted here):

```
exports = module.exports = (req, res, admin) => {
    // allowed domains for this API endpoint
    let domains = [
        'http://localhost:4200',
        'http://localhost:4300',
        'http://localhost.local',
        'http://www.localhost.local'
    ];

    // make sure that only above domains are accessing it, otherwise return error
    if (typeof req.headers.origin !== 'undefined') {
        if (domains.indexOf(req.headers.origin) === -1) {
            return res.status(403).send({
                'status': 'error',
                'type': 'not-authorized',
                'message': 'You\'re not authorized to use this method!'
            });
        }
    } else {
        return res.status(403).send({
            'status': 'error',
            'type': 'malformed-request',
            'message': 'Your request is missing CORS origin header!'
        });
    }

    // errors
    let errors = [];

    // process uploaded form
    const busboy = new Busboy({headers: req.headers});

    // process attached fields
    busboy.on('field', function(fieldname, val) {
        req.body[fieldname] = val;
    });

    // now process the results
    busboy.on('finish', () => {
        let report_object = {},
            report_object_location = {},
            report_key = admin.database().ref().child('/reports/').push().key;

        // check "location" and process if
        if (typeof req.body.report_address !== 'undefined') {
            if (req.body.report_address !== '') {
                report_object['reports/' + report_key + '/location/address'] = req.body.report_address;
                report_object['reports/' + report_key + '/location/unknown'] = false;

                if (typeof req.body.report_latitude !== 'undefined') {
                    report_object['reports/' + report_key + '/location/latitude'] = parseFloat(req.body.report_latitude);
                }

                if (typeof req.body.report_longitude !== 'undefined') {
                    report_object['reports/' + report_key + '/location/longitude'] = parseFloat(req.body.report_longitude);
                }

                // Google Maps API for geocoding and reverse geocoding
                const googleMapsClient = require('@google/maps').createClient({
                    key: 'xxx'
                });
                console.log('address: ', req.body.report_address);
                if ((typeof req.body.report_latitude === 'undefined' || req.body.report_latitude === '0' || req.body.report_latitude === '' || req.body.report_latitude === 0) && typeof req.body.report_address !== 'undefined') {
                    console.log('geocoding executed');
                    googleMapsClient.geocode({'address': req.body.report_address, 'components': {'country':'XX'}}, function(error, response) {
                        if (!error) {
                            console.log('formatted: ' + response.json.results[0].formatted_address);
                            report_object_location['address'] = response.json.results[0].formatted_address.replace(', <country name>', '');
                            report_object_location['latitude'] = response.json.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
                            report_object_location['longitude'] = response.json.results[0].geometry.location.lng;

                            // added so that the data is saved directly and was hoping it won't be overwritten
                            report_object['reports/' + report_key + '/location/address'] = response.json.results[0].formatted_address.replace(', <country>', '');
                            report_object['reports/' + report_key + '/location/latitude'] = response.json.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
                            report_object['reports/' + report_key + '/location/longitude'] = response.json.results[0].geometry.location.lng;

                            response.json.results[0].address_components.forEach(result => {
                                if (typeof result.types !== 'undefined') {
                                    if (result.types[0] === 'locality') {
                                        report_object_location['city'] = result.long_name;
                                        report_object['reports/' + report_key + '/location/city'] = result.long_name;
                                    }
                                }
                            });

                            console.log('geocoding complete', new Date().getTime());
                            admin.database().ref('/reports/' + report_key + '/location').update(report_object_location);

                        } else {
                            console.log(error);
                        }
                    });
                }
            } else {
                errors.push({
                    'field': 'report_address',
                    'type': 'missing',
                    'message': 'Please enter address'
                });
            }
        } else {
            errors.push({
                'field': 'report_address',
                'type': 'missing',
                'message': 'Please enter address'
            });
        }

        // check category and process it
        if (typeof req.body.process !== 'undefined') {
            if (req.body.process !== '') {
                report_object['reports/' + report_key + '/category'] = utils.firebaseKeyEncode(req.body.process);
            } else {
                errors.push({
                    'field': 'process',
                    'type': 'missing',
                    'message': 'Please select process'
                });
            }
        } else {
            errors.push({
                'field': 'process',
                'type': 'missing',
                'message': 'Please select process'
            });
        }

        // check "subject" and process it
        if (typeof req.body.subject !== 'undefined') {
            if (req.body.subject !== '') {
                report_object['reports/' + report_key + '/subject'] = utils.firebaseKeyEncode(req.body.subject);
            }
        }

        // check "reporter" and process if
        if (typeof req.body.reporter_name !== 'undefined' && req.body.reporter_name !== '') {
            report_object['reports/' + report_key + '/reporter_name'] = req.body.reporter_name;
        }
        if (typeof req.body.reporter_address !== 'undefined' && req.body.reporter_address !== '') {
            report_object['reports/' + report_key + '/reporter_address'] = req.body.reporter_address;
        }
        if (typeof req.body.reporter_phone !== 'undefined' && req.body.reporter_phone !== '') {
            report_object['reports/' + report_key + '/reporter_phone'] = req.body.reporter_phone;
        }
        if (typeof req.body.reporter_notify !== 'undefined' && req.body.reporter_notify !== '') {
            report_object['reports/' + report_key + '/reporter_notify'] = true;
        }
        if (typeof req.body.reporter_email !== 'undefined' && req.body.reporter_email !== '') {
            const emailValidator = require('email-validator');
            if (emailValidator.validate(req.body.reporter_email)) {
                report_object['reports/' + report_key + '/reporter_email'] = req.body.reporter_email;
            } else {
                errors.push({
                    'field': 'reporter_email',
                    'type': 'invalid',
                    'message': 'Entered email is not valid!'
                });
            }
        }

        // check "note" and copy it
        if (typeof req.body.notes !== 'undefined') {
            if (req.body.notes !== '') {
                report_object['reports/' + report_key + '/notes'] = req.body.notes;
            }
        }

        // add current user
        report_object['reports/' + report_key + '/created_user_display_name'] = 'Website';

        // add created date & statuses
        report_object['reports/' + report_key + '/datetime'] = admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
        report_object['reports/' + report_key + '/status'] = 'open';
        report_object['reports/' + report_key + '/status_updates/open'] = admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;

        // any errors?
        if (errors.length > 0) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                'status': 'error',
                'type': 'invalid-data',
                'message': 'Please fix the data you provided data and re-submit.',
                'errors': errors
            });
        }

        // trigger function that saves the data
        return exports.saveReportDetails(report_object, report_key, res, admin);
    });

    // required, otherwise the upload hangs
    busboy.end(req.rawBody);
    req.pipe(busboy);
};
```

Function that saves the data into database:

```
exports.saveReportDetails = function(report_object, report_key, res, admin) {
    // add icon marker
    admin.database().ref('/settings').once('value', settingsData => {
        admin.database().ref('/categories/' + report_object['reports/' + report_key + '/category']).once('value', categoryData => {
            let settings = settingsData.val(),
                category = categoryData.val(),
                description = (typeof category.subjects[report_object['reports/' + report_key + '/subject']] !== 'undefined' && typeof category.subjects[report_object['reports/' + report_key + '/subject']].description !== 'undefined' ? category.subjects[report_object['reports/' + report_key + '/subject']].description : '');

            report_object['reports/' + report_key + '/marker_icon'] = {
                url: category.icon,
                color: category.marker_color,
                scaledSize: {
                    width: settings.map_marker_icon_size,
                    height: settings.map_marker_icon_size
                }
            };

            let report_history_key = admin.database().ref().child('/reports_history/' + report_key + '/history').push().key;
            report_object['reports_history/' + report_key + '/' + report_history_key + '/action'] = 'created';
            report_object['reports_history/' + report_key + '/' + report_history_key + '/datetime'] = parseInt(moment().format('x'), 10);
            report_object['reports_history/' + report_key + '/' + report_history_key + '/user_display_name'] = 'Website';
            report_object['categories_reports/' + report_object['reports/' + report_key + '/category'] + '/' + report_key] = true;

            if (report_object['reports/' + report_key + '/subject'] !== 'undefined') {
                if (typeof category.subjects !== 'undefined') {
                    if (typeof category.subjects[report_object['reports/' + report_key + '/subject']] !== 'undefined') {
                        let subject = category.subjects[report_object['reports/' + report_key + '/subject']];
                        if (typeof subject.handling_days !== 'undefined') {
                            report_object['reports/' + report_key + '/handling_days'] = subject.handling_days;
                        }

                        if (typeof subject.user_key !== 'undefined' && typeof subject.user_display_name !== 'undefined') {
                            // report should be assigned to user
                            let report_history_key2 = admin.database().ref().child('/reports_history/' + report_key + '/history').push().key;
                            report_object['reports/' + report_key + '/assigned_user_key'] = subject.user_key;
                            report_object['reports/' + report_key + '/assigned_user_display_name'] = subject.user_display_name;
                            report_object['reports/' + report_key + '/assigned_user_type'] = subject.user_type;
                            report_object['reports/' + report_key + '/assigned_datetime'] = admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
                            report_object['reports/' + report_key + '/status'] = 'assigned';
                            report_object['reports/' + report_key + '/status_updates/assigned'] = admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
                            report_object['reports_history/' + report_key + '/' + report_history_key2 + '/action'] = 'assigned';
                            report_object['reports_history/' + report_key + '/' + report_history_key2 + '/assigned_user_key'] = subject.user_key;
                            report_object['reports_history/' + report_key + '/' + report_history_key2 + '/assigned_user_display_name'] = subject.user_display_name;
                            report_object['reports_history/' + report_key + '/' + report_history_key2 + '/datetime'] = admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
                            report_object['reports_history/' + report_key + '/' + report_history_key2 + '/user_key'] = false;
                            report_object['reports_history/' + report_key + '/' + report_history_key2 + '/user_display_name'] = 'auto-assigned';
                            report_object['users_assigned_reports/' + subject.user_key + '/' + report_key] = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (typeof report_object['reports/' + report_key + '/subject'] !== 'undefined') {
                report_object['subjects_reports/' + report_object['reports/' + report_key + '/subject'] + '/' + report_key] = true;
            }

            let year = moment().format('Y');
            admin.database().ref('/reports_count/' + year).once('value', data => {
                let value = data.val();
                let number = 0;
                if (value !== null) {
                    number = parseInt(value, 10) + 1;
                } else {
                    number = 1;
                }
                report_object['reports/' + report_key + '/unique_number'] = year + '#' + number;

                // assume all files have uploaded and push data into firebase
                admin.database().ref('/').update(report_object);
                console.log('save report', new Date().getTime());

            });

            // send confirmation email?
            console.log(report_object['reports/' + report_key + '/reporter_email']);
            if (typeof report_object['reports/' + report_key + '/reporter_email'] !== 'undefined') {
                if (report_object['reports/' + report_key + '/reporter_email'] !== '' && report_object['reports/' + report_key + '/reporter_email'] !== false) {
                    const emails = require('./../utils/mailTransportModule');

                    emails.mailTransport.verify(error => {
                        if (error) {
                            console.log(error);
                        } else {
                            admin.database().ref('/settings').once('value', function(settings_data) {
                                let settings = settings_data.val(),
                                    webapp_name = (typeof settings.webapp_name !== 'undefined' ? (settings.webapp_name !== '' ? settings.webapp_name : '<webapp name>') : '<webapp name>'),
                                    webapp_url = (typeof settings.webapp_url !== 'undefined' ? (settings.webapp_url !== '' ? settings.webapp_url : '<webapp url>') : '<webapp url>'),
                                    support_email = (typeof settings.support_email !== 'undefined' ? (settings.support_email !== '' ? settings.support_email : '<webapp email>') : '<webapp email>'),
                                    support_phone = (typeof settings.support_phone !== 'undefined' ? (settings.support_phone !== '' ? settings.support_phone : '-') : '-'),
                                    message = {
                                        from: `"${webapp_name}" <${support_email}>`,
                                        to: report_object['reports/' + report_key + '/reporter_email'],
                                        replyTo: '<replyTo email>',
                                        subject: `<subject>`,
                                        text: emails.emails.newReportConfirmationText(webapp_name, report_object['reports/' + report_key + '/datetime'], utils.firebaseKeyDecode(report_object['reports/' + report_key + '/category']), (report_object['reports/' + report_key + '/subject'] !== false && typeof report_object['reports/' + report_key + '/subject'] !== 'undefined' ? utils.firebaseKeyDecode(report_object['reports/' + report_key + '/subject']) : ''), (description !== 'undefined' ? description : ''), (report_object['reports/' + report_key + '/location/address'] !== false ? report_object['reports/' + report_key + '/location/address'] : '-'), support_email, support_phone),
                                        html: emails.emails.newReportConfirmationHTML(webapp_name, webapp_url, report_object['reports/' + report_key + '/datetime'], utils.firebaseKeyDecode(report_object['reports/' + report_key + '/category']), (report_object['reports/' + report_key + '/subject'] !== false && typeof report_object['reports/' + report_key + '/subject'] !== 'undefined' ? utils.firebaseKeyDecode(report_object['reports/' + report_key + '/subject']) : ''), (description !== 'undefined' ? description : ''), (report_object['reports/' + report_key + '/location/address'] !== false ? report_object['reports/' + report_key + '/location/address'] : '-'), support_email, support_phone),
                                        attachments: []
                                    };

                                let images = _.filter(report_object, function(v, k){
                                    return _.includes(k, '/images');
                                });
                                // check if any image or audio is available and attach them to the message
                                if (images.length) {
                                    images.forEach((image, index) => {
                                        if (image.startsWith('https://')) {
                                            message.attachments.push({
                                                filename: 'image_' + index + '.jpg',
                                                href: image
                                            });
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                                emails.mailTransport.sendMail(message).then(() => {
                                }).catch(error => {
                                    return Promise.reject('sendMail error: ' + error, message);
                                });
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

            return res.status(200).send({
                'status': 'success',
                'type': 'report-saved',
                'message': ' Report was successfully saved.'
            });
        });
    });
};
```

I am hoping that I have missed something basic and someone can shed some light onto what, since I am lost with what else to do.

Package JSON for Functions:

```
{
    "name": "<name>",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "description": "<description>",
    "dependencies": {
        "@google-cloud/storage": "^1.5.2",
        "@google/maps": "^0.4.5",
        "busboy": "^0.2.14",
        "connect-busboy": "0.0.2",
        "email-validator": "^1.1.1",
        "express": "^4.16.2",
        "firebase-admin": "^5.8.1",
        "firebase-functions": "^0.8.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.4",
        "moment": "^2.20.1",
        "nodemailer": "^4.4.1",
        "sharp": "^0.19.0",
        "uuid-v4": "^0.1.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node index.js",
        "build": ""
    },
    "private": true
}
```

UPDATE:
Example object before geocoding:

```
{
  "assigned_datetime" : 1536661321150,
  "assigned_user_display_name" : "<name>",
  "assigned_user_key" : "<key>",
  "assigned_user_type" : "<type>",
  "category" : "<category>",
  "created_user_display_name" : "<name>",
  "created_user_key" : "<key>",
  "datetime" : 1536661321150,
  "location" : {
    "address" : "<full address>",
    "city" : "<city>",
    "latitude" : <decimal>,
    "longitude" : <decimal>,
    "unknown" : false
  },
  "marker_icon" : {
    "color" : "#2962ff",
    "scaledSize" : {
      "height" : 38,
      "width" : 38
    },
    "url" : "assets/img/icons/blue.png"
  },
  "notes" : "<notes>",
  "printed" : true,
  "reporter_address" : "<address>",
  "reporter_email" : "<email>",
  "reporter_name" : "<name>",
  "reporter_notified" : 1537282713509,
  "reporter_phone" : "<phone>",
  "send_email" : true,
  "status" : "resolved",
  "status_updates" : {
    "assigned" : 1536667369830,
    "open" : 1536661321150,
    "resolved" : 1537282713367
  },
  "subject" : "<subject>",
  "unique_number" : "<number>"
}
```

Example object after geocoding and saving into `reports/<report_key>/location`:

```
{
  "location" : {
    "address" : "<full address>",
    "city" : "<city>",
    "latitude" : <decimal>,
    "longitude" : <decimal>,
    "unknown" : false
  }
}
```

Comment: Please check if this is the same (very common) problem as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53458434/why-does-update-completely-overwrites-my-data-in-firebase-set-vs-update/

Comment: Also FYI many of your Firebase and Google dependencies appear to be *very* old.

Comment: Not sure if it is, since the problem is that the object at `reports/<report_key>` gets replaced with "new" object of `location`, despite I did set a full path to `reports/<report_key>/location`. From the docs, only `location` should be updated and not that entire report object is replaced with `location`.

Comment: Have added object examples to describe the problem. Do note that I also tried using multi-path update, so I updated each object specifically, like `reports/<report_key>/location/address = <address>`, still got back second example.

Comment: Pretty sure it's the same.  When you update a child at a location (the ref where you call update ()), the entire contents of the child location are replaced with what you specify.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm following correctly, but a call like this `report_object['reports_history/' + report_key + '/' + report_history_key + '/action'] = 'created';` should only update the value of the `action` property. If that doesn't happen for you, please edit your question down to the [minimal complete code that I can run to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Forgot to mention that there's even a bigger issue, for most of the time the code above works properly and from time to time, it simply replaces the object. I can't reliably reproduce the issue ...