# Firebase real-time database deletes old data and replaces it

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I want to add a new data on my real time database. However Database deletes old data and write new data. My data scheme like that :

[image]

And I want to add a new user on rooms/roomid/users/

My code part :

```js
joinRoom = async (callback = f => f, roomId) => {
        
        currentRoomUid = roomId
        var username = ''
        await database().ref(`/users/${auth().currentUser.uid}`).once('value', function (snap) {
            username = snap.val().username
        })

        const room = database().ref(`/rooms/${roomId}`);
        await room.set({
            isStart: true,
            currentQuestionIndex: 0
        });

        const usersRef = database().ref(`/rooms/${roomId}/users`)
        usersRef.child(auth().currentUser.uid).set({
            username: username,
            skor: 0
        });

        callback(roomId)
    }
```

The important point here is where I add the user. I use the set method. How can I fix it ? I want to add the second user.

The Problem

Old Data

[image]

After adding operation

[image]

Comment: Calling `usersRef.child(auth().currentUser.uid).set(...)` overwrites the data at `usersRef.child(auth().currentUser.uid)`. But that seems correct to me. What do you want it to do instead?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen For Example I want to add a new user that's key is 2. And old user's key is 1. so I'm sure the Key of two users is not the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.set() method will delete your old data and will create new data.
so when you using room.set, you deleting everything in room.
that's include users.
so every time user enters a room he will delete the previous user and add himself instead.
you should use room.update
like this:

```
const room = database().ref(`/rooms/${roomId}`);
    await room.update({
        isStart: true,
        currentQuestionIndex: 0
    });
```

if you want to know better the different between set and update read the answer for this question:
[Firebase update vs set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38923644/firebase-update-vs-set)

here is the full code you should use:

joinRoom = async (callback = f => f, roomId) => {

```
    currentRoomUid = roomId
    var username = ''
    await database().ref(`/users/${auth().currentUser.uid}`).once('value', function (snap) {
        username = snap.val().username
    })

    const room = database().ref(`/rooms/${roomId}`);
    await room.update({
        isStart: true,
        currentQuestionIndex: 0
    });

    const usersRef = database().ref(`/rooms/${roomId}/users`)
    usersRef.child(auth().currentUser.uid).set({
        username: username,
        skor: 0
    });

    callback(roomId)
}
```

Comment: Thank you. However I want to add a new data on my users part.

Comment: I have edited to answer, let me know if it still not the solution

Comment: Thank you for everything. Your answer is correct. I should have used update instead of set. The problem was caused by this.The room was being wiped because I set it first.

Answer (score 2):

#### Update following your comments:

If you want to add different `users` under the `rooms/423c34.../users` node, you need to pass different values to the `child()` method. For example:

```
        const usersRef = database().ref(`/rooms/${roomId}/users`)
        await usersRef.child('userKey1').set({  
            username: username1,
            skor: 0
        });

        await usersRef.child('userKey2').set({   
            username: username2,
            skor: 0
        });
```

---

If I correctly understand your question, the following adaptations should do the trick:

```
joinRoom = async (callback = f => f, roomId) => {
        
        currentRoomUid = roomId
        var username = ''
        const snap = await database().ref(`/users/${auth().currentUser.uid}`).once('value');
        const username = snap.val().username;
    
        const room = database().ref(`/rooms/${roomId}`);
        await room.set({
            isStart: true,
            currentQuestionIndex: 0
        });

        const usersRef = database().ref(`/rooms/${roomId}/users`)
        await usersRef.child(auth().currentUser.uid).set({   //Note the await here
            username: username,
            skor: 0
        });

        callback(roomId)
    }
```

---

Note that you didn't `await` the last call to the `set()` method, so most probably the callback was executed before the new user was persisted to the Database.

---

Note also that you may use the [`update()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference?authuser=0#update) method, to "perform simultaneous updates to multiple locations in the JSON tree with a single call".

Comment: Unfortunately. this solutin didn't work. It still deletes old data and then add new data

Comment: It is not clear what you exactly mean by old data and new data. Look at Frank comment above, he has a similar question. As soon as you use `auth().currentUser.uid` for calling `child()`, you will always overwrite the same node, which corresponds to the authenticated user. How do you differentiate the users, i.e. the old data and new data.

Comment: For example, the old data belongs to a user. This user's key is 1 name Frank and the user I want to add is Bob and Key 2. I am sure that the key of the old data is not the same as the key of the new data.

Comment: Yes you are right. I am sure it has different key but I try again with static datas.

Comment: So you need to pass keyX to `usersRef.child(auth().currentUser.uid).set(...)` as follows `usersRef.child('keyX').set(...)`

Comment: I added two picture on my question

Comment: I solved my problem. I did not notice the effect of the code block I wrote before. Unfortunately the problem was caused by it. Since I set the same room before, the room was completely deleted and added again. Sorry for stolen your time. Thanks.