# Does multiple updates on single document in a transaction incur write cost for each update separately in Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, transactions

For example will `update(sfDocRef, "population", newPopulation)` and
`update(sfDocRef, "count", newCount)` be counted as separate document write. Or should i use set() method

```
db.runTransaction { transaction ->
    val snapshot = transaction.get(sfDocRef)

    val newPopulation = snapshot.getDouble("population")!! + 1
    val newCount = snapshot.getLong("count")!! + 1
    it.apply {
         update(sfDocRef, "population", newPopulation)
         update(sfDocRef, "count", newCount)
    }  
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is considered as a seperate write operation. It is better to combine those. I think this will help you. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38924648/11783181)